# Showing that $\int_{R^d} \nabla_\theta f(\theta) \pi(\mbox{d}\theta) = 0$.

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus

Assume that $f(\theta)$ is a sufficiently regular function (Lipschitz etc.) and $\pi$ is a probability measure defined as,
$$\pi(\mbox{d}\theta) \propto \exp(-f(\theta)) \mbox{d}\theta.$$
I want to show that
$$\int_{R^d} \nabla_\theta f(\theta) \pi(\mbox{d}\theta) = 0.$$
In the paper I am reading, it is said that it is "a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus". My knowledge is limited for that theorem when the functions are integrated against probability measures. How can we prove this statement?

To be more specific, one can assume $\pi(\mbox{d}\theta)$ has a density:
$$\pi(\theta) = \frac{\exp(-f(\theta))}{\int_{R^d} \exp(-f(\theta')) \mbox{d}\theta}$$

then the claim will become: $$\int_{R^d} \nabla_\theta f(\theta) \pi(\theta) \mbox{d}\theta = 0.$$

Comment: Does this writing makes sense? $\nabla_\theta f(\theta) \pi(\theta) $ the gradiant is a vector so check it again there is something missing

Comment: Maybe you are right, but if $\int_{R^d} \nabla_\theta f(\theta) \pi(\mbox{d}\theta)$ makes sense and $\pi$ has a density, how can I write the integral with the density?

Comment: In that case it suffices to consider $\partial_\theta f(\theta) \pi(\theta) $

Comment: What is the difference between $\partial_\theta f(\theta)$ and the gradient?

Comment: No that is partial derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assume that f vanish at inifty then you have**  and $$\pi(\theta) =c \exp(-f(\theta))$$
Then we have, 
$$\int_{\Bbb R^d}\partial_{\theta_1} f(\theta) \pi(\theta)d\theta= c\int_{\Bbb R^{d-1}}\int_{\Bbb R}\partial_{\theta_1} f(\theta) \exp(-f(\theta_1, \theta'))d\theta_1d\theta'\\=-c\int_{\Bbb R^{d-1}}\int_{\Bbb R}\partial_{\theta_1}\left(\exp(-f(\theta_1, \theta'))\right)d\theta_1d\theta'\\=c\int_{\Bbb R^{d-1}}\left[\exp(-f(-\infty, \theta'))-\exp(-f(\infty, \theta')) \right]d\theta'=0 $$
Hence,

$$\int_{\Bbb R^d} \nabla_\theta f(\theta) \pi(\theta) \mbox{d}\theta = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks, I can use this. I assume $f$ is strongly convex, so $f$ would explode at the infinity. But in that case, $\exp(-f(-\infty,\theta')) = 0$ and similarly for $\exp(-f(\infty,\theta'))$, so the proof is still valid, no?

Comment: in this case $\exp(-f(-\infty,\theta')) = 1$ you did precise where f should be taken